# Show Message Bar in ribbon mfc

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, ribbon, ribbon-control

Probabbly i am not sure what to search for ... But the idea is to display a message bar bellow ribbon control. When user try to edit a read only file. I don't want user to click on OK to remove error message. Thats why i can't use MessageBox.

Status bar doesn't seem right place to display error messages.

Which control i should start exploring.

MSOffice normally displays such message when user opens files in protected view .

I don't want you to do research for me, I just want the right direction i will do the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use CMFCCaptionBar for such an attempt. When you create a ribbon bar SDI application you get sample code for free.

Also it is possible to hide and Show such a bar on the fly with ShowWindow. Also this code is generated by the wizard.